# Proof for vectors

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, vectors

I am struggling with solving tasks on vectors. The task:
Prove that the end of vector $\vec c$ lies on the segment joining the ends of vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ if and only if the equality

$$\vec c = m\vec a+n\vec b \, , \quad m \geq0 \, , \quad n \geq0 \, , \quad m+n=1$$

is satisfied. In what ratio does the end of vector $\vec c$ divide this segment?

The statement that $\vec c$ is decomposed by vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is quite intuitive since $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ vectors are coplanar vectors. But I couldn't prove equality $m+n=1$. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: If you do not impose the condition $m+n=1$, then you can write a fourth of the plane in this manner!! How are you expressing the assumption that $c$ lies on the line joining the ends of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I have tried to write the vector c, through ma and nb, based on similar triangles, but have not got explicit proof that m+n=1

Comment: No similar triangles. How do you parametrically represent *all* points on the line through $\vec a$ and $\vec b$? Write a *vector* equation.

Comment: @TedShifrin, if I understood correctly, the parametric equation of all points on the line through a and b would be n(-a+b), where n is between 0 and 1.

Comment: @KirillDegtyarev That is said points' positive relative to $\vec{a}$, i.e. they're actually at $\vec{a}+n(\vec{b}-\vec{a})$.

Answer (score 0):

Note $m+n=1$ is one of the defining conditions of the locus you're asked to prove is the specified line segment; it's not something you have to "prove" separately. Since $m\vec{a}+n\vec{b}=\vec{a}+n(\vec{b}-\vec{a})$, the given parameterization is precisely of the points a proportion $n\in[0,\,1]$ of the way from $\vec{a}$ to $\vec{b}$.

Comment: I think the OP might be stuck on the converse of what you've written. But let's find out.